# How can I use FireEvent's touchStart option in userEvent

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, user-event

I'm studying test using jest, and React testing-library.
I have a question about userEvent.

There is a `touchStart` option in fireEvent.

How can I use `touchStart` option in userEvent.

`fireEvent.touchStart(screen.getByRole('button'));`
Please let me know

Comment: Didn't support "touch" events yet. https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/880